# Verify the mouse hover menu items list in Selenium

Tags: selenium, mousehover

I am trying to get the selenium automation script to get the list of mouse hover menu items.

Launch the web browser 
Find the required element i.e. ‘Music’ object in our sample
Now move the mouse on ‘Music’ option which will display the submenu list
Get all the list of elements showing up under 'Music' option.

I am able to mouse hover on the Music object using 'Actions' class but couldnt figure out how to get the submenu as a list.